# ¿Cuál es la frase equivalente a "I'm going to rock your world"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-modismo

Estoy tratando de encontrar una frase en español que transmita un mensaje equivalente al de *"I'm going to rock your world"* en inglés.

La frase en inglés quiere decir que vas a cambiar, para mejorar, el mundo de una persona. Se utiliza normalmente cuando estás a punto de transmitir un mensaje que mejorará la vida de una persona significativamente.

Nota: No estoy buscando una traducción palabra por palabra, eso lo puedo hacer yo, pero no tiene el mismo impacto.

Comment: Las frase que se me ocurren pueden ser tanto para algo bueno como malo o tienen una clara connotación sexual.

Comment: @blonfu puedes compartir la frase?

Comment: Voy a transformar tu vida, voy a cambiar tu realidad.

Comment: Lo que encuentro con google es "cambiar tu vida para siempre".

Answer (score 1):

No hay ninguna frase similar a "I'm going to rock your world". Al menos, no que yo sepa.

Quizás la más cercana o similar podría ser "Voy a transformar tu mundo", lo cual denota que algo va a cambiar, aunque no se sabe si sea para bien o mal (dependiendo de tu propósito), aunque en tu caso, si se piensa que sea un cambio positivo en la persona.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser:
Voy a conmocionar tu mundo

Conmoción:
Movimiento o perturbación violenta del ánimo o del cuerpo.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez "Voy a sacudir tu mundo" (o "su mundo" si "your" es ustedes/vosotros).

(En mi opinión "rock your world" sólo significa "cambiar, sacudir", y es el contexto de uso lo que le da/daría connotación positiva.)